# In ASP.NET MVC, create form for only one member of view model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and I am trying to create a page which lists a number of items and also contains a small form for creating a new item.
So I created this view model:

```
//The view model has the list of items as AllItems and a member variable for creating a new item.
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public List<SListItem> AllItems { get; set; }

    //SListItem contains ID, Name and price
    public SListItem NewItem { get; set; }
}
```

In my razor file, I add the line:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewItem.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
```

In the html output, it creates a text input with the name set to "NewItem.Name" instead of "Name"

```
<input name="NewItem.Name" id="NewItem_Name" type="text" value="">
```

In the controller, that receives the POST data submitted through the form

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,ItemType")] ShoppingListItem item)
{
}
```

When I run it, the "item" parameter does not get populated because the form elements have the name "NewItem.***"

How do I overcome this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your action method is expecting an object of type `ShoppingListItem`, but you view is bound with `IndexViewModel`. As @Stephen said you need to change the input parameter of your action method to `IndedxViewModel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better off using a separate model for the `NewItem` property. You can call `@Html.Action()` to render the form for the `NewItem` model as a child action of the index view.

Your index view would look like this:

```
@model Your.Namespace.IndexViewModel

<div>
    <!-- your index markup -->

    <!-- call this wherever the child view should render -->
    @Html.Action("whatever_you_name_the_action")
</div>
```

And your "edit" view would look like

```
@model Your.Namespace.SListItem 

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.WhateverPropertyOfSListItemYoureAfter)
```

You just need to make sure you return a `PartialView` rather than a `View` from the child action. If you want to have a "special" controller action that cannot be requested directly, mark the action with the `ChildActionOnlyAttribute`. For example:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    return PartialView("_SListItemView");
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
I tried this and it works great.
Although, I just want to add that in the Edit action, I return
PartialView("_SlistItemView", new SListItem());
Thanks!!

Comment: If your `SListItem` model has properties that need to be setup in the constructor (like a `List` or similar), then yeah, that's a good idea. Otherwise, you don't really need to supply a model.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the signature of the post method to

```
HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel model)
{
   string name = model.NewItem.Name;
}
```

Comment: When I do this, I get this error:
Additional information: The entity type IndexViewModel is not part of the model for the current context.

Comment: Firstly, have you checked that the model is now correctly populated? I think that error is raised by the entity framework and is likely to be as a result of what you are passing to your DbContext method (you haven't shown the code in your Index method so hard to tell exactly)

Answer (score 1):

in your razor file add following code
`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewItem.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",@Name='name'} })`

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: Thanks! This one works too.
Just a note that it does not work when you set @name = "name"
It has to be sentence case \\@Name = "name"

Comment: Ignore the slashes in front of the @. A problem with stackoverflow

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. @Name will set the name attribute for the specified HTML element that is going to be rendered serverside.